# Class rectangle with raw_input of cartesian coordinates?

Tags: python, class, object

Help! I have this program due tomorrow, the requirements are that it must have the X,Y  cartesian coordinates of the topLeft corner and the X,Y cartesian coordinates of the bottomRight corner as raw_input. Then it prints the perimeter, area and those two positions. 
However I cannot get the raw_input to work. I have tried converting it to int, splitting, and multiple assignments.

```
topLeft = int(raw_input ('Please enter a coordinate==>')).split()
bottomRight= int(raw_input ('Please enter a coordinate==>')).split()
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, topLeft, bottomRight):
        self.tL = topLeft
        self.bR = bottomRight
    def perim(self):
        return (2 * (self.tL)) + (2 * (self.bR))
    def area(self):
        return (self.tL) * (self.bR)
    def position(self):
        return (self.tL, self.bR)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Rectangle(%s, %s)" % (self.tL, self.bR)

r1 = (Rectangle (topLeft,bottomRight))
print r1
print "Perimeter: %s" % r1.perim()
print "Area: %s" % r1.area()
print "Position: (%s, %s,)" % r1.position()
```

This is my closest attempt, but I still get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mary\Desktop\Python Programs\Rectangle.py", line 1, in <module>
    topLeft = int(raw_input ('Please enter a coordinate==>')).split()
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(5,10)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How was that going to work? You did a lot of mistakes.

```
tx, ty = raw_input("tx ty: ").split() # the input is "4 5", int("5 4")??? 
bx, by = raw_input("bx by: ").split()
```

Then

```
self.tx = int(tx)
self.ty = int(ty)
# and so on ...
# If you want to work with tuples `(xt,yt)` Make both int first.
```

. And all you class methods are incorrect, for instance `perimeter = 2*(bx-tx) + 2*(ty-by)` not `2*(tx,ty) + 2*(bx,by)`. Semantically it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am a beginner, thank you for all your help! I went in and adjusted my class methods, I got those for someone else but yours made so much more sense. I didn't realize I needed to check for integers within the class itself. It now works perfectly.

Comment: A better approach to deal with coordinates is to make them feel natural using `collections.namedtuple`, which are loosely tiny *class* factories. if `P` is a point namedtuple class, you could do `top = P(x=xt, y=yt)` and `top.x top.y`. It will look very natural.